# What is the usage of port option in kubectl expose

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I'm not clear about the usage of port option in the command `kubectl expose deployment demo ---port=8080 --target-port=8080 --type=NodePort`

I know this command is used to expose a deployment to external and the `target port` is the port on the container. After running this command, Minikube would randomly assign a port on the node. Then I could access my service by this port. How about the usage of the `--port` option? Is it the port for the user/client in the cluster?

Comment: I find that currently in `kubectl`, you couldn't choose the exposed port. What you could: a) using `kubectl expose deployment demo ---port=8080 --target-port=8080 --type=NodePort` and then using `kubectl edit` change the config. b) using a yaml file to create the service for deployment.

Answer (score 3):

Per the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#expose), `kubectl expose` exposes a resource as a new Kubernetes service where:

- `--port` is "...The port that the service should serve on. Copied from the resource being exposed, if unspecified".
- `--target-port` is "...Name or number for the port on the container that the service should direct traffic to. Optional".

So, the `--port` flag specifies the port on which the service will be accessible. It is to note that for [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) type, "...the Kubernetes control plane allocates a port from a range specified by --service-node-port-range flag (default: 30000-32767)".

If you want to affix the NodePort port, and assuming the default settings, try using a port number in the range above. For example:

```
kubectl expose deployment demo --port=31080 --target-port=8080 --type=NodePort
```

Another option could be to use `kubectl create service nodeport` with proper `node-port` flag. It is documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-service-nodeport-em-).

This may be a personal preference but as much as kubectl run, expose, and similar commands are convenient, I'd rather work with ([declarative](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/)) configuration files that are checked in and versioned in a code repo than with [imperative commands](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/imperative-command/) :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, so I if I use a port, like 8080, not in the range 30000-32767, it would be assigned randomly, right?